# Unable to upload code to Arduino Mega in Ubuntu VM (computer is Win10)

Tags: arduino, virtual-machine

I'm trying to upload code to an Arduino-Mega in Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using Oracle Virtual Machine to run Ubuntu and my computer is Win10.

From Win10, the port the Arduino is using is COM3. In the VM settings, I have these settings for Serial Port 1: [image: VM Serial Port 1 Settings]

In Ubuntu, I run 'sudo arduino' in the terminal and compile my code. 
In the Arduino IDE, the only Serial Port I can connect to is ttyS2:
[image: Serial Port Details]

When I try to upload the code, I get these error messages:
[image: Error Messages]

Before, I kept having the error message "Native Serial Port, can't obtain info", but now I just get these error messages.

Any help is appreciated, thank you everyone!

Comment: are you sure the Arduino is COM3?

Comment: Do the ports disappear/reappear when you unplug/replug the arduino? In Windows? In Ubuntu?

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I checked the using the Device Manager. The Arduino was using COM3

Comment: @datafiddler I tested that in Windows, and yes it disappears and reappears. I haven't checked in Ubuntu, but I will only be able to test that on Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simple, I forgot to select the Arduino in the Ubuntu environment (Devices > USB > Arduino)